# How make a register form codeigniter with different database table

Tags: codeigniter, user-roles, multi-user

I tried to make a register form on a multiuser website with a different database table.

Eg when user1 registers, the data will be entered in table "user1", 
when user2 registers, entered in table "user2".

I can only enter user1 and user2 into the same table.
This is my code using role_id

```
$data = [
            'name' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('nama', true)),
            'username' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('username', true)),
            'photo' => 'default.jpg',
            'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password1'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'role_id' => 2,
            'is_active' => 1,
            'is_date' => time()
        ];
```

Comment: this is bad practice, create only one table *users*, where you store user-data and a unique user_ID. Imagine you have 10k users, then you'd need 10k tables... read about [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying condition on `role_id` but this is only possible if there are only a number of users. If there are many users and you want to make a separate table for each one of them, try [**`Database Forge Class`**](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/forge.html)(Bad practice)

I've written a possible solution for your question, comments are mentioned wherever necessary. See if it helps you.

**Controller**

```
$data = [
            'name' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('nama', true)),
            'username' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('username', true)),
            'photo' => 'default.jpg',
            'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password1'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'role_id' => 2,
            'is_active' => 1,
            'is_date' => time()
        ];

$this->xyz_model->xyz_function($data); // load xyz_model and call xyz_function with $data parameters
```

**Xyz_model**

```
function xyz_function($data){

    $table = 'user1'; // default value

    if($data['role_id'] != 1){ // other value is 2 -- assuming only 2 users are there(if not user if else or switch)
        $table = 'user2';
    }

    $this->db->insert($table, $data);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```